# Group Policy Preferences: Content Advisor disabled

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

We decommissioned our last Windows 2008 R2 server, and with it goes the ability to edit Internet Explorer Maintenance policy settings.

Moving forward is Group Policy Preferences... so, I open up Group Policy Management, create a new GPO > User Config > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Internet Settings > right-click > New Internet Explorer 10 > Content tab.

And the Content Advisor buttons are greyed out.

How do I enable these buttons, so that I might configure the Content Advisor?

Thanks!

[image]